# How to fix a wardrobe in double plasterboard?

Tags: drywall, cabinets, drywall-anchor

I started fixing a wall-mounted-wardrobe via rail (BOAXEL Ikea) onto the bedroom wall using geefix and snaptoggle. It was all fine as my walls are 12.6mm gypsum-carton plaster, followed by a hollow bit - so I could anchor beautifully. However, when I drilled into the middle section of the wall, it seems that I have no hollow cavity anymore, but a double layer of plasterboard. I am scared to drill all the way through the second plaster as there might be a third section of plasterboard and then reach the other room!

Now the question is, what can I use to fit the wardrobe through this thickness? I would really prefer something as heavy duty as possible.. many thanks!

Comment: 1) It's best to know how your walls are constructed before hanging anything heavy on them, 2) You don't tell us what you're hanging, 3) It's not clear what you DO know.  "Doubled up plaster" .. what is that?   Drwyall/sheetrock?  A double layer of 12.5mm drywall?  Please clarify what you mean by "plaster".   4) If it is drywall, depending on what you are hanging, a light weight 20mm toggle might do.  5) It really matters if it's hollow, or there is plywood behind it, or brick, or maybe wires or pipes ... you need more info.

Comment: if there are two layers of drywall in one spot, it could be a patched spot. There was a hole at some point and it was fixed by attaching a drywall piece from behind. I used this method when cut a whole in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will try to be specific. 1) This is a partition wall, between the bedroom and the bathroom. There is no brick / rock in between. When I drilled most of the holes, I found 2x 12.5mm plasterboard made out of gypsum and cardboard with a gap in between. I used snaptoggles here. 2) I mentioned that I am hanging a wall-mounted wardrobe(165cm)via rails, it is a BOAXEL from Ikea.  3) I do know that most of the wall is made with 2x12.5mm drywall with a hollow in-between; but this middle strip has no hollow and instead two 12.5mm drywall layers (so I suspect 3 in total).

Comment: @jay613 I replied above, hope this is enough info.

Comment: Most of the wall is: |drywall| hollow |drywall|. The middle strip is: |drywall|drywall|?drywall I assume|. Therefore I cannot use toggles in the middle strip because I have no hollow.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @anm767, I drilled 2 holes, one towards the top, one towards the bottom (vertically), to see if it was patched in one particular place. However the wall was the same with no hollow in both places.

Comment: There is something I don't understand about your description.  Usually hollow walls are supported by wood or metal [studs](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=stud+walls&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover) in between.  Sometimes there is a double layer of drywall on one side of the studs, or on both sides.  The way you describe your wall the hollow space is only 12.5mm wide and in one place is filled with another layer?   So you have a wall that is *entirely* composed of tow or three layers of drywall?  No structure?  What is holding it up?

Comment: If it is a normal hollow wall, if you drill through the plaster where it is hollow, you should then be able to stick a screwdriver to a depth of about 50mm before hitting the back of the opposite wallboard.   Can you?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Using a stud-finder, I could identify 2 vertical wood studs. The stud-finder did not find a wood stud over this middle problematic strip. Hence, I was surprised to not find the normal "hollow" behind the plasterboard depth. I do not have any drilled open holes where I can measure the hollow. But the 50mm long screws I tried to use the first time were a bit too long, as they hit the next plasterboard layer. I assume therefore that the hollow depth is < 38mm.

Comment: @jay613 I replied above, hope this helps

Comment: Ok so no one else replied with solutions so this is what I did: I used an undercutting tool of 25mm and drilled behind the plasterboard into the next plasterboard to create space for blue Gripits flaps to open up. I fitted the 8 x 25mm blue Gripits. The M8 screws that came with the Gripits were much too large for the vertical rail holes I needed to fit. I therefore also drilled with a size 8 drillbit into the metal rail to enlarge the gap. It worked, my wardrobe is still up - but goodness me what a nightmare this was....